# Is there a GraphicsMagick equivalent to ImageMagick's image stack?

Tags: imagemagick, graphicsmagick

Although GraphicsMagick is a fork of ImageMagick, there are dissimilarities between the two, namely in the support of image stacking in ImageMagick, but not in GraphicsMagick. Taken from the ImageMagick documentation:

```
convert wand.gif \( wizard.gif -rotate 30 \) +append images.gif
```

In this example, the `rotate` command is applied **only** to the `wizard.gif` resource. My question is: **Is there an equivalent to image stacking in GraphicsMagick?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is nothing like this in GraphicsMagick.  If you are willing to write a script using one of the scripting extensions, or write a C/C++ program using the GraphicsMagick library, then anything becomes possible.